# Can't delete/format drive partition

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning

I don't know how this partition was created. Only I am using this computer, so I thought it is probably from some software program that I've installed. I've uninstalled all programs but this partition is still there, I still can't remove/format/delete it.

It is 300MB and as you can see in the picture it has some used space. But when I open it, it is empty.

Tried with Disk Managment on Windows 7 and no luck.

[image: Inserted Image]

Comment: You can use [Easeus partition magic](http://www.partition-tool.com/download.htm) which has ability to delete it at boot time. But make sure you have any restore point or repair disk if any error occur due to it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you install Windows 7 via Microsoft Deployment Toolkit (MDT)? MDT automatically creates a partition called "BDEDrive" and reserves it for BitLocker (even if BitLocker is not used at all).

If you are certain that you are not using BitLocker, you can do the following to delete the partition:

1. Start a command shell with administrator privileges and type `bcdboot c:\windows /s c:`
   (assuming that c: is your system partition)
2. Start the *Disk Management* and mark your c: partition as *active*
3. Reboot

Afterwards you can delete the BDEDrive partition.

Comment: No, i didn't install from MDT. Just i don't know when exaclty but short time after installation this appeared there and i can't remove it. @Phillip R. link tell same. I'll try just i can't reboot right now.

Comment: It's possible the partition was created during the OEM/system builder stage. Be sure you're not using BitLocker first!

Comment: How can i check if i use or not ? i just made step 1 and 2 from @speakr answer and will reboot later.

Comment: @JasonPaddle Open the _Control Panel_, then _BitLocker Drive Encryption_. If you use BitLocker, you will see the details there ([example](http://iboyd.net/wp-content/uploads/2009/05/bitlocker-control-panel.jpg)). Make sure that all your partitions/drives have BitLocker disabled.

Comment: @speakr I have only C:(wich is system) and D: second partition and they both are Off.

Comment: I'm on other PC now and i don't have BitLocker in Control Panel. Why is that ?

Comment: @JasonPaddle Please check [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BitLocker_Drive_Encryption#Availability) for information regarding BitLocker availability.

Answer (score 0):

[Technet](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserversecurity/thread/74783472-3776-4b9e-a8f4-7ab777bd99d9) forum shows a guy who was able to delete it.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Thank you i will try it in a while and will post the result here. I can't reboot right now thats why